# If product has custom options, then echo out div on list.phtml

Tags: custom-options, magento-1.6, php-5.4, list.phtml

I'm fairly new to Magento and looking at PHP code is just daunting to me so I'm trying to learn by doing.
I've been looking into making my own "Free Gift" label for items on my store but no extension I've found is able to give me the specific functionality I require. Basically if the product has an option with the label "Free Gift" then echo out my .

I managed to get some code that does this perfectly except it displays the Free Gift label on any product that has an option available (size for example).

```
<?php if ( $_product->getData('has_options') && ($_product->getTypeID() == 'simple') ): ?>
<div class="free_gift_text"><?php echo "Free Gift" ?></div>; 
<?php endif; ?>
```

If I place this code in my theme files (media.phmtl, list.phtml) then it works like I want it to except with the problem above (as the code only looks for if the product has options)

Now below I have some different code that works PERFECTLY on the product pages.

```
<?php

$theoptions = $_product->getOptions();
foreach($theoptions as $opkey=> $opval)

if(( $_product->getData('has_options')) && ($_product->getTypeID() == 'simple') && ($opval->getTitle() == 'Free Gift')): ?>
   <div class="free_gift_text"><?php echo "Free Gift" ?></div>;
<?php endif; ?>
```

But it doesn't work when I place it in list.phtml, no labels show up at all. I'm not sure why this is but I think it's because it can't read if the products had options or not.

I'm not sure if I'm going the wrong way about this or if there's a different solution to this but any help would be massively appreciated as I'm not very experienced in PHP, Thank you.

Comment: Can you confirm that `$_product` is product object in `list.phtml` too?

Comment: Yes, I see it referenced in other places in list.phtml

Comment: Your code must be inside the `foreach` loop where `$_product` is called (ex. `foreach ($_productCollection as $_product)`.

Comment: From where you get $opval? you need to retrieve option value for product on listing page.

Comment: I'm only trying to get the option label, not the actual value

Comment: `getTypeID()` should be  `getTypeId()`

Comment: @josephdrury yes but for that you need to retrieve product options as you did on product page.

Comment: @Mufaddal Ah ok, so how do I do that? I'm failing to understand why this works on my product pages but not on the product listing pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On listing page you cant get product custom option directly,,for that you have to load `$_product` object

write below code in your `list.phtml`

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>

<?php $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_product->getId()); ?>
```

and then write your logic

```
    <?php 
$theoptions = $product->getOptions();
foreach($theoptions as $opkey=> $opval)
{
    if(( $product->getData('has_options')) && ($product->getTypeID() == 'simple') && ($opval->getTitle() == 'Free Gift')): ?>
       <div class="free_gift_text"><?php echo "Free Gift" ?></div>;
    <?php endif; ?>   
}
?>
```

> Note::It may down your web speed perfomance on listing page because it every
>   time load `product object`

Comment: That's giving me a syntax error
'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)'
about 100 lines down

Comment: Please do not perform a `load` on the `catalog/product` model in a foreach. This will cause huge issues on busy production shops. Especially when the feature requested is purely cosmetic. There will be an other solution by, probably, adding some data to the collection

Comment: @josephdrury post your list.phtml

Comment: @SanderMangel i know that it down web speed performance that why i have added notice

Comment: @KeyurShah I posted it here http://codepad.org/2CcY508o from line 261

Comment: @josephdrury see my edit

Comment: @josephdrury see http://codepad.org/JsE6lPaU

Comment: @KeyurShah That works! Thank you! Was it just missing '<?php endforeach; ?>' ? 
If you post this as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_option')` collection method to retrieve options collections of product

Use `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_option')->getProductOptionCollection($_product)` method to retrieve option collection of product.

You don't need to load product every time in `foreach`.